# How to save an image when button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating an application there is a save button to save an image in another view controller. i.e., press the save button on one view controller and image should be saved on another view controller and it should not remove until i manually do with delete button in my app.

I tried with NSUserDefault but if i closed the app and reopen it the saved image is automatically remove.  How to preserve that image until the user made manually.

```
//view controller 1 
if(count == 0) {
    [testArray addObject:imageArray[0]];
    [testArray addObject:imageArray[1]];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:testArray forKey:@"testArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

//view controller 2
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"testArray"];
```

Or else i want to know how to save or pass an image in one view controller to another view controller.

Comment: you may save image to database and load it in an other view. If you don't use data base u can store image to document dir. NSUserDefaults should not be used to store data as global dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should save image in **Document Directory**

```
 - (IBAction)saveImage {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *image = imageView.image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   
}
```

in Another ViewController **get image**

```
  - (IBAction)getImage {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
}
```

**Remove image**

```
     - (void)removeImage
    {
      NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
      NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

      NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
     BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
      if (success) {
          UIAlertView *removeSuccessFulAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation:" message:@"Successfully removed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
          [removeSuccessFulAlert show];
[imageview removeFromSuperview];
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"Could not delete file -:%@ ",[error localizedDescription]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: i pressed the delete button image remove alert is woking and image also removed from that place in Document folder but the imageview is not removed if i go to home and come back the imageview is removed. How to removed instantly in image view.

Comment: set imageview.image=nil

Comment: thanks …. but i have one doubt if i save ten image and i set image view.image = nil what will happen it will remove one image or ten image.

Comment: no you have to use after remove so image will be move after delete

Comment: how to use array instead of image string …

Comment: you have to apply for loop and save the image for particular path